# <hr> equivalent in C# and XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf

I apologize if this question seems too simple but I really wanted to know how I'm able to achieve this through c# as I have a wpf app and am trying to use it as a divider for a series of content. Currently, I'm aware of the Environment.NewLine but I need a physical line and not a `<br>`.

I've tried searching for it but all of them are giving the `<br>` solution. The most I could search was from this site, which unfortunately yielded nothing: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?231842-html-lt-HR-gt-in-C

Comment: Yes, use a Separator. You may also achieve it with RichTextBox, but it's a way of pain, don't even look at that direction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `<Separator />` element, or a `<Border>` or even a `<Grid>` or a `<Rectangle>` with a small height:

```
<Border Height="1" Background="Red" />

<Grid Height="1" Background="Red" />
```